# Changing the state of a context within an if-else in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, react-context

I tried making a global state by using a Context and have the following for my AuthProvider.js file

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

I want to be able to change its boolean state within an if-else instead of a button with an onCLick event in the tutorial but it shows an error in the console: setAuth is not a function

```
function Home() {
    
  const setAuth = useContext(AuthProvider);

  const [usernameReg, setUsernameReg] = useState("");
  const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const [loginStatus, setloginStatus] = useState("");

  const uLogin = document.getElementById('userLogin');
  const pLogin = document.getElementById('passwordLogin');

  const register = () => {
    if (usernameReg === "" || passwordReg === ""){
      alert("Fields can't be blank");
      return;
    }
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register', {
      username: usernameReg,
      password: passwordReg,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  const login = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.message){
        setloginStatus(response.data.message);
        alert(response.data.message);
      }
      else{
        setloginStatus(response.data[0].username);
        
        
        setAuth(true);   <====================================== here


        window.location.href = "/map";
        

      }
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }


  return (
    <div className="Home">
           
              
           <h1>Register</h1>
              <label>Username: </label>
              <input type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                setUsernameReg(e.target.value)
              }}/>
              <label><p></p>Password: &nbsp;</label>
              <input type="text"
                onChange={(e)=> {
                setPasswordReg(e.target.value)
              }}/>
              <p></p>
              <button onClick={register}> Register </button>
          

          <h1>--------------------------------------------------------</h1>

          {/*<form id="loginForm">*/}
            <h1>Log In</h1>
            <input id="userLogin" type="text" placeholder="Username"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUsername(e.target.value)
              }}
            />
            <p></p>
            <input id="passwordLogin" type="password" placeholder="Password"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPassword(e.target.value)
              }}
            />
            <p></p>
            <button  onClick={login}> Log In </button>
          {/*</form>*/}  
          

          <h1>{loginStatus}</h1>

          
    </div>
  )
}
```

my App.js is below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter,Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import MapPage from "./Pages/MapPage.js";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./ProtectedRoutes";
import { AuthProvider } from "./components/AuthProvider"



function App() {

  const  [auth, setAuth ] = useState(false);
  //const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  return (  
    <BrowserRouter>
      
      <Routes element ={<AuthProvider />} value={{auth, setAuth}}>
        
        <Route element ={<ProtectedRoutes />}>

            <Route element={<MapPage />} path="/map" exact/>

        </Route>

        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>

      </Routes>
      
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { AuthProvider } from './components/AuthProvider'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bitly/CRA-vitals
reportWebVitals();
```

I'm very new to JavaScript and I've only been following along tutorials for the functions or features I need for the project. Is there a way for this?

I'm also guessing that the code for the context file is overkill for a simple Boolean state.

Comment: is this code giving you an error, then please state it,  also post the whole code for the home function

Comment: const setAuth = useContext(AuthProvider) // this line might be causing the error, here setAuth is an object and inside login() you are trying to update the state like this setAuth(true), so make some changes const {setAuth, auth} = useContext(AuthProvider)

Comment: I tried that, but the website wont render and returns this console log:
```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setAuth' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: is home your app's entry point (root component) and if it is then you need to wrap it using <AuthProvider></AuthProvider>

Comment: I've provided my App.js in the post, I'm trying to make it so that a user won't be redirected to back to the home page after an if-else verifies that they've logged-in

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example

Comment: remove this line  <Routes element ={<AuthProvider />} value={{auth, setAuth}}> and check if its working

Comment: I've removed `element ={<AuthProvider />} value={{auth, setAuth}`  and the same error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setAuth is not a function
    at Home.js:58:1` shows up

Comment: I apologize that this isn't minimal and reproducible. This is my first time asking and I guess also have a hard time finding where the problem is in a big volume of code. I will delete this question soon

Comment: after removing it, did you try to destructure it as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to check the [context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) again, and try to understand how and why you set them up, and how to access them. You tried accessing the context by passing the provider as a param to the useContext hook. This is wrong, you need to pass the Context itself. You also called the return from the context setAuth, but the return is the context itself. I urge you to read the documentation thourougly. However, this is probably what you wanted:

```
type AuthContextType = {
    auth: boolean;
    setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

const useAuthContext = () => {
    const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (!ctx) throw new Error("No AuthContext Provider found");

    return ctx // as AuthContextType<...> if you need the context to be generic and to infer generics.
};

function Home() {
    const { auth, setAuth } = useAuthContext();
    ...
}
```